# Нужно вернуть массив, состоящий только из неуникальных элементов данного массива

Tags: python, list, filter, lambda

Функция должна возвращать такие значения

```
checkio([1, 2, 3, 1, 3]) == [1, 3, 1, 3]
checkio([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) == []
checkio([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]) == [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
checkio([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8]) == [10, 9, 10, 10, 9]
```

Хочу решить эту задачу не используя одни только циклы for вложенные друг в друга. Попытался решить задачу с помощью filter, но столкнулся с ошибкой ('int' object has no attribute 'count'), а так же понимаем частичного непонимания работы lambda функции:

```
def checkio(data: list) -> list:
    data = filter(lambda x: x.count(x)>1, data)
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

ну почти сделали

ошиблись только в 1 месте - вместо `x.count(x)` надо было указать `data.count(x)`

ну и хорошо бы после `filter` результат перевести в список, поскольку изначально это просто итерируемый объект

```
def checkio(data: list) -> list:
    return list(filter(lambda x: data.count(x)>1, data))

print(checkio([1, 2, 3, 1, 3]))
print(checkio([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
print(checkio([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]))
print(checkio([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8]))
```

Comment: Точно, спасибо большое, не могли бы вы подсказать в чем отличия между list(решение) и [решение], вроде же одно и то же, а второй вариант не работает

Comment: `list(решение)` будет эквивалентно `[*решение]`

Comment: спасибо большое